# Wipe and re-install Android 2.2 on Droid2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-2

I used to have a Motorola Droid, and I loved it because it was barebones Android, none of that flashy aftermarket crap they put on it to make it appeal more to consumers. No, I like my android plain, how it comes straight from Google.

So I was slightly disappointed to find out that with the Motorola Droid2, Motorola installed their own flavor of Android with a bunch of extra shit that I don't want.

So my question to you is, is it possible for me to wipe out and re-install a base Android 2.2 on my device? Will there be any problems? If this is possible, a link to a tutorial or better yet, step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, but it took a lot of research and time. Here's what I did, probably not exactly like this since it took me a few tries to get right:

Root your phone.

Download the Koush Bootstrapper/loader and install it onto your phone, via their site or the Android Market.

Go to [Team DeFuse's](http://www.teamdefuse.com/Team_DeFuse/index.html) website to download the Fission 2.2 ZIP file. Put this on your SD card somewhere.

Boot into Koush, apply the bootloader patch, and then reboot into the bootloader.

Clear cache/data, mount /data and /system, clear cache/data again, install update, select ZIP file on SD card, once that's done, clear cache/data again, and then reboot.

You should then boot into a fresh install of "vanilla" Froyo Android. No apps. No settings. And best of all, **no Motoblur!**

... I think I got all that right. If I missed something, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is possible.  Haven't done it myself, but [this](http://www.mwd.com/2010/10/install-frf91-android-2-2-froyo-vanilla-fission-rom-on-droid-2/) looks promising.

It indicates that you need to be rooted and already have Koush’s Droid X Bootstrap Recovery installed, but from there it looks like a matter of simply applying the ROM .zip file from Recovery.

Comment: I don't want to root my phone, I just want vanilla Android. An official Google-released ROM would be preferrable.

Comment: I see you were able to get it up and running using a similar method.  Well done, and enjoy!